# Does declaring a variable cost an overhead?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

My lead always asks me to get rid of the new variables as much as I can saying it costs an overhead. However, I'm not sure if that actually degrades the performance. If anything, making new variables improves the readability of my code. Does it actually worsen the performance?

Option 1:

```
var a = something1();
var b = something2();
var c = something3();
var d = something4(a, b, c);
```

option 2: Making it just one line of code.

`var d = something4(something1(), something2(), something3());`

Please note: at times, it gets complicated and the readability worsens.

Comment: That's premature optimization at its worst. Do what's most legible. Worry about the overhead when you've measured it and it's shown to be causing problems. Their compacted suggestion is bad.

Comment: You can wrap that function call on multiple lines for both readability, and reduced overhead (which may be just additional mental parsing).

Comment: This is subjective, but I find the option 1 far less readable.

Answer (score 2):

In the strictest sense, yes a variable uses resources (memory or processing). But that alone doesn't mean it's bad or wasteful. Use a variable to make your code more readable and/or to store data that will be needed to be reused.

Later, when it's time to QA your work you can worry about optimization. And there is a very well-known mantra in software development that trying to optimize your code as you initially write it often leads to more problems than it solves.

But I have to say that if having something in a variable is causing your performance to suffer, you've got other problems to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

Both options are almost the same for the performance. With the option 2 all function calls are evaluating to a hidden internal memory space which is bound to the function parameters. This is almost an equivalent to assigning vars in option 1.

Comment: This is a good point

Answer (score 0):

If you use variable once, get rid of it. If 2+ times - declare variable.
Variable can be declared in this case only if too many executions make debug tricky. Therefore if action fits in line - it is better to use `option 2`

No change in performance. Just readability that also can be affected by too big amount of variables.

Comment: I wouldn't even necessarily agree with that. If a calculation is getting long, breaking it up using a well-named intermediate can greatly help readability. I personally use single-use intermediates all over the place when the line they're a part of is becoming convoluted. (I didn't downvote though. The downvote is probably because this doesn't actually address the question).

Comment: @Carcigenicate agree, therefore I've mentioned about fitting in line. Because even debugging can be tricky. But imho too big amount of simple variables decreases readability even more.